# Changing JS Indenting in Atom Keymap.cson

Tags: javascript, keymapping, atom-editor

I'm trying to update my `keymap.cson` file so that JavaScript source is indented slightly differently. I do not want it to de-indent `case` and `default` statements in a `switch`.

By default, Atom will format this way:

```
switch(x) {
case 1:
    //stuff
case 2:
    //stuff
default:
    //stuff
}
```

I like my case statements to be indented once (and `//stuff` to be indented once more).

So I'm trying to edit my keymap to make it format things this way:

```
switch(x) {
    case 1:
        //stuff
    case 2:
        //stuff
    default:
        //stuff
}
```

Unfortunately, whatever I try, I can't get it to stop decreasing the indentation as soon as I hit the spacebar after "case".

From [the Keymaps Documentation](https://atom.io/docs/latest/advanced/keymaps) it looks like putting the following coffeescript in my `keymap.cson` file should disable the default behavior and add my new behavior (which omits `|case|default` from the second line of the regular expression) *should* do the trick but I'm not sure why it's not working:

```
'.source.js':
    'editor':
        'decreaseIndentPattern': 'unset!'

'.source.js':
  'editor':
    'decreaseIndentPattern': '(?x)
        ^(.*\\*/)?\\s*(\\}|\\))
      | ^\\s* else \\s*$
      '
```

I *think* the original keymap is [in the language-javascript package here](https://github.com/atom/language-javascript/blob/master/scoped-properties/language-javascript.cson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined that this probably isn't technically a Keymap so it can't be overridden in `keymap.cson`. What I ended up doing was [forking the language-javascript repo](https://github.com/yeldarby/language-javascript), making my change, uninstalling the original `language-javascript` package, and installing my custom fork instead.

Would still like to know if there is a way to update this at runtime instead; with this solution I will have to manually keep my fork up to date with any upstream changes.

Edit: Just an update for this particular change, it was actually accepted into the official `language-javascript` package [via PR #36](https://github.com/atom/language-javascript/pull/36).

Comment: As of this writing, there isn't a way to update grammars at runtime in the way that you're asking.